# Using strptime to parse timestamp relative to the local time

Tags: perl

I am trying to do some date calculation relative to the current local time. 
For example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $fmt = '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S';
my $timestamp = "2015-04-12_11:07:27";

# This gives incorrect $t1 relative to localtime
my $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime( $timestamp, $fmt );
my $t2 = localtime;

say "Local time: " . localtime;
say "Local time epoch: " . time;

say $t1->epoch();
say $t2->epoch();

my $timestamp1 = $t1->strftime( $fmt );
my $timestamp2 = $t2->strftime( $fmt );

say $timestamp1;
say $timestamp2;

my $delta = $t2 - $t1;

say $delta;
```

A sample output:

```
Local time: Sun Apr 12 12:21:49 2015
Local time epoch: 1428834109
1428836847
1428834109
2015-04-12_11:07:27
2015-04-12_12:21:49
-2738
```

Which clearly gives the a wrong time difference of -2738. ( It should be a positive number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the date-time you parse has no time zone information, it's assumed to be UTC. You can see this by adding the following two lines in your script:

```
say "tzo1 = ",$t1->tzoffset;
say "tzo2 = ",$t2->tzoffset;
```

In Paris, the above outputs the following:

```
tzo1 = 0
tzo2 = 7200
```

You can override the default to be the local time zone by using the undocumented feature of using `localtime` instead of `Time::Piece` as the invocant.

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -E'
   say Time::Piece->strptime("2015-04-12_11:07:27", "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")->tzoffset;
   say localtime  ->strptime("2015-04-12_11:07:27", "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")->tzoffset;
'
0
7200
```

Doing that minor change gives the answer you were expecting.

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -E'
   say localtime->strptime("2015-04-12_11:07:27", "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S") - localtime;
'
5524
```

Comment: Yes I think that is the case, but how can I do this correctly? Or maybe it is not possible with Time::Piece ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be done using [`Date::Time`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) :

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use DateTime::Duration;

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern   => '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S',
    time_zone => 'local',
);

my $timestamp = "2015-04-12_11:07:27";
my $dt1 = $strp->parse_datetime( $timestamp );
my $dt2 = DateTime->now();
say $dt2->subtract_datetime_absolute( $dt1 )->seconds();
```